# Parseval-Plancherel type identity for probability generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions, parsevals-identity

Assume that $f,g \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and define the Fourier transform of $f$ by $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm{e}^{-i\,x\,\xi}\, f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\xi, \quad \xi \in \mathbb R.$$
The well-known Parseval-Plancherel identity links the $2$-norm of $f-g$ and the $2$-norm of $\hat{f} - \hat{g}$ via $$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)-g(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{2\,\pi}\,\int_{\mathbb R} |\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{g}(\xi)|^2\,\mathrm{d} \xi \label{1}\tag{1}.$$
Now suppose that $f = (f_0,f_1,\ldots) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ and $g = (g_0,g_1,\ldots) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ are probability distributions over $\mathbb N$, and define for each $z \in (0,1)$ the probability generating function of $f \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ by $$\hat{f}(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} z^n\,f_n. $$ I am wondering if there exists a "natural" analog of the Parseval-Plancherel identity \eqref{1} involving the probability generating function. Unfortunately, I did not find any useful reference or related literature about this question.

---

Edit: Motivated by the answer provided by Andrew, I am wondering if there exists a collection of functions (not necessarily a orthonormal basis) $\{\varphi_n(z)\}_{n \geq 0}$ such that $$f_n = \int_0^1 \hat{f}(z)\,\varphi_n(z)\,\mathrm{d} z \label{2}\tag{2}$$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. I want to view \eqref{2} as a sort of analog of the inverse Fourier transform (but now it involves the probability generating function instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow yourself to extend the domain of $\hat f$ to the closed complex unit circle, you can come up a result. For $|z|\leq 1$, we can see that the sum $\hat f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}f_nz^n$ absolutely converges because $$\sum_{n\geq 0}|f_nz^n|=\sum_{n\geq 0}f_n|z|^n\leq \sum_{n\geq 0}f_n =1$$

Consider the function $\bar{f}:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$ given by $\bar{f}(n)=f_n$ for $n\geq 0$ and $\bar{f}(n)=0$ for $n<0$. $\bar{f}$ gives the coefficients of the Fourier series of $\hat f(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n\geq 0}f_ne^{in\theta}$. The same is true for $g$.

We can use Parseval's Theorem for Fourier series.

$$\|\bar g-\bar f\|^2=\|\hat g-\hat f\|^2\implies\sum_{n\geq 0}(f_n-g_n)^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|\hat{f}(e^{i\theta})-\hat{g}(e^{i\theta})|^2d \theta$$

On the other hand, if we want a identity involving $\int_0^1(\hat{f}(z)-\hat{g}(z))^2dz$, we can use the shifted Legendre polynomials $\tilde P_k$ (defined by $\tilde P_k(z)=P_k(2z-1)$). Let $a_k$ be the following. $$a_k = (2k+1)\int_{0}^1 \tilde P_k(z)\hat{f}(z)dz$$ We can write $a_k$ in terms of the probabilities by using the unform convergence of $\hat f$ as follows.
$$a_k = (2k+1)\int_{0}^1\sum_{n\geq 0}f_n \tilde P_k(z)z^ndz=(2k+1)\sum_{n\geq 0}f_n\int_{0}^1 \tilde P_k(z)z^ndz$$ I don't have the exact form of these integrals on hand, but they should be computable in general. You can trivially prove that it is zero if $n<k$. Therefore, there exists some constants $C_{n,k}$ such that $$a_k=\sum_{n\geq k} C_{n,k} f_{n}$$ If we define $b_k$ anaologusly for $g$, we can use the Parseval's theorem for Legendre-Fourier Series. $$\int_0^1(\hat{f}(z)-\hat{g}(z))^2dz=\sum_{k\geq 0}(a_k-b_k)^2$$
This is of course, much less pretty. If you choose other orthogonal polynomials with different weight functions on $[0,1]$ you should be able to get different $C_{n,k}$ but this won't make the final form any nicer.

Comment: Hello, can you elaborate your short answer? Here in the discrete setting the probability generating function $\hat{f}(z)$ is only defined for $z \in (0,1)$. I have no clue as to why you assumed that the argument of $\hat{f}(\cdot)$ can be a complex number.

Comment: The sum for $\hat{f}(z)$ converges absolutely for any complex number $z$ such that $|z| = 1$ (and indeed for any $|z| \leq 1$). This is trivial to prove because $\sum_{n\geq 0} |f_nz^n|=\sum_{n\geq 0} f_n=1$. It is therefore well defined on these points.

Comment: Also, the sum in the Parseval identity for Fourier series should be $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ instead of $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}$. I really want to emphasize that we require that the domain of the definition of the p.g.f $\hat{f}(\cdot)$ to be $[0,1]$, as has been set-up very clearly in the original post.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more complete. As for extending the function to the complex plane, I want to be clearly that it is not something I came up with. You even can see it on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Univariate_case) for the pgf. If you have a good reason for only looking at $z$ real, the realistic answer is that there's no identity. You need complex numbers somewhere for a Parseval identity. Furthermore, if you want something of the form $\sum_{n\geq 0}(f_n-g_n)^2$, the identity I gave is still true and it would equal the rhs also

Comment: May I ask why you need $z$ to be real? Is it some nuance with your application? Or have I been going in the wrong direction and what care about is $\int_0^1 (f(z)-g(z))^2 dz$. In that case, I believe there is another identity using Legendre polynomials but it’s much less pretty on the $f_n$ side.

Comment: Yes the "realistic" application I have in mind must require that $z \in [0,1]$ to be real number. If you want to do "integration", then I am seeking a relation (or inequality) between $\sum_{n\geq 0} |f_n - g_n|^2$ and $\int_0^1 |\hat{f}(z) - \hat{g}(z)|^2 \,\mathrm{d} z$ (or some other related quantities).

Comment: Also, can you elaborate your last sentence "there is another identity using Legendre polynomials but it’s much less pretty on the $f_n$ side". I am eager to learn the details. Pointing me to the reference paper/monograph/notes will also be highly appreciated

Comment: Hello Andrew, thank you again for your informed answer. Can you look at the updated original post and see if it is possible to establish (2)?

Comment: Since we are looking at $f_n$ arbitrary, what we are looking for is equivalent to a set of functions $\phi_n$ such that for any analytic function $f$, the value of the functional $\int_0^1\phi_n(z)f(z) dz$ is $f^{(n)}(0)$. But, there is only one such functional and its corresponding 'functions' are the Dirac Delta distribution and its derivatives.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. If you don't mind, may I ask a last question? Take $f, g \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$, I am wondering if it is possible to upper bound $\sum_{n\geq 0} |f_n - g_n|^2$ by some quantity involving $\int_0^1 \left(\hat{f}(z)-\hat{g}(z)\right)^2 \,\mathrm{d} z$ or involving $\int_0^1 \frac{\left(\hat{f}(z)-\hat{g}(z)\right)^2}{(1-z)^2} \,\mathrm{d} z$ ... Otherwise, it will be appreciated if you can give explicit expressions for the set of coefficients $a_k$ in your original answer.